# License Verification Library – How to test server response

Tags: android, google-play, android-lvl

I have already wasted days with what seams to be an error in the Google license verification framework.

I am testing the Google market License Verification Library. I have thus far:
 - created a library and test project from the provided library and sample sources with no changes (except public key and other obvious things).
 - created a publisher account on market
 - I have not uploaded the application to the market
 - installed the sample application to a device
 - In the developer console added test accounts
 - I have set various test responses in the developer console

My problem is that I always get a NOT_MARKET_MANAGED response - regardless of settings in the developer console test response.
The docs state that I have to be signed in a device with a publisher account. It does not say what does this mean specifically.
I have added a publisher account to the accounts in the device but this does not help. Since the License Library depends on Market application I have changed the account in Marker application. No effect either.
I have googled around and found something in the line "… that I have to be signed in with publisher account as primary account…". What exactly is primary account remains vague. Some sources state that a factory reset is needed for a primary account sign in. I have not tried that but I think you loose whatever you made on the device, installs, messages, contacts and such. This is impossibly impractical.
My question is: How does one test the application against various responses?

Comment: 'I have not uploaded the application to the market' and 'I always get a NOT_MARKET_MANAGED response' seem to be the key statements here...

Comment: I've implemented LVL in a couple of apps and written a [server side verification library](http://code.google.com/p/android-market-license-verification/). You have to upload your application so that the Android Market is aware of your package or it is going to respond 'Not Market Managed'. Upload a draft application and then you can play with the forced responses.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On the developer console it is clearly stated:

> This License Test Response will be sent to devices using
>   publisher_account or the Test Accounts listed above for applications
>   you have uploaded to Market. Additionally, this account (but not the
>   Test Accounts) will receive this response for applications **that have
>   not yet been uploaded to Market**.

The same is also stated in this section of docs:

http://developer.android.com/guide/publishing/licensing.html#test-acct-setup

I know that testing is possible with uploading the apk to the server. But besides setting the test response in developer console one has to do:

1. Compile the application without debug flag
2. Create a certificate
3. Sign the apk with certificate
4. Upload the apk to the server

All this is a major PITA. Something that could be just a simple run and test is now a whole procedure, just for testing the most basic functionality of a prototype.

Taken into consideration the discrepancy between the docs and License Verification Framework behavior there is only one possible conclusion. Either docs or implementation (or both) are flawed.

Comment: I've had exactly the same experience with this as you. While David Caunt's approach may be a valid workaround, the [Android documentation](http://developer.android.com/google/play/licensing/setting-up.html) clearly states that it is possible for the account owner to 'check license _before_ upload', both in figure 4 and table 1.

Answer (score 1):

Please read the [Official Dev Guide](http://developer.android.com/guide/publishing/licensing.html#test-env) carefully:

> **Setting test responses for license checks**
>
> Android Market provides a configuration setting in your publisher account that lets you override the normal processing of a license check and return a specified static response code. **The setting is for testing only and applies only to license checks for applications that you have uploaded**, made by any user signed in to an emulator or device using the credentials of the publisher account or a registered test account. For other users, the server always processes license checks according to normal rules.

And follow David's comments.